# How to make a time format in Jspinner?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

How to make a time format like this 
hourhour:minuteminute:secondsecond,milisecondmilisecondmilisecond

using only one Jspinner when I make this spinner using visual GUI of NET beans.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use both, `SpinnerDateModel` and `JSpinner.DateEditor` with the correct date format pattern:

```java
public class JSpinnerDateFormat extends JFrame {
    public JSpinnerDateFormat() {
        super("JSpinner Date Format");
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        spinner.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel());
        spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
        add(spinner);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JSpinnerDateFormat();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want the jspinner take the current time of my computer.

I want when I give a time as a input, the jspineer take it
And as I wish I can increase or decrease.
how can I do this?

Comment: Please read the docs! For example, you can set the value with `spinner.setValue(myDate);`. Increase and decrease are built in to JSpinner, just give it a try!